# error while writing a simple twitter streaming program in scala spark - Too many login attempts in a short period of time

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, twitter4j

This is my program:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder

object TwitterHashtagStreaming {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterHashtagStreaming").setMaster("local[*]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
    println(ssc.getState())

    if (!Logger.getRootLogger.getAllAppenders.hasMoreElements) {
      Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
    }
    // (1) config work to create a twitter object
    val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    val tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build())
    val twitter = tf.getInstance().getAuthorization()
    println(twitter)

    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(twitter))
    stream.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(10000)
    ssc.stop()
  }
}
```

this is `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Test1"
    
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.0"


libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.3"
```

when I run the program I get the error:
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=4d13a6ae or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b77019f1

```
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[4d13a6ae-b77019f1], statusCode=420, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
20/10/28 14:30:04 INFO TwitterStreamImpl: Waiting for 10000 milliseconds
20/10/28 14:30:04 INFO TwitterStreamImpl: 420:Returned by the Search and Trends API when you are being rate limited (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).
Returned by the Streaming API:
 Too many login attempts in a short period of time.
 Running too many copies of the same application authenticating with the same account name.
Easy there, Turbo. Too many requests recently. Enhance your calm.


java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.log(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.logInfo(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStop(TwitterInputDStream.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.stopReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply$mcV$sp(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:189)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/10/28 14:30:04 INFO TwitterStreamImpl: 420:Returned by the Search and Trends API when you are being rate limited (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).
Returned by the Streaming API:
 Too many login attempts in a short period of time.
 Running too many copies of the same application authenticating with the same account name.
Easy there, Turbo. Too many requests recently. Enhance your calm.
```

Can you please help me to fix this error?
I receive the error when I add this statement to my program -
`val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(twitter))`

Comment: You are likely getting rate limited [Rate limits|Docs|Twitter Developer](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits)

Comment: Or you have multiple instances of your program running simultaneously.